# Convert <a> tag to <span> if href contains something and remove href

Tags: php, html, regex, replace

Hi I'm using wikipedia api and images come with html output. But don't want to link images to wikipedia, i just want to show them. So I want to convert `<a>` tags to `span` or `div` which they are for images. Also href must be deleted How can I do it with php?

Input

```
<a href="/wiki/Dosya:House_in_Cappadocia_22.jpg" class="image">
    ...(img tag, captions etc)
</a>
```

Output should be (if href contains "Dosya");

```
<span class="image">
     ...(img tag, captions etc)
</span>
```

Comment: HTML parsing with RegEx ... I feel a link to *that* answer coming on...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose: you have a string having this content

```
$string = '<a href="/wiki/Dosya:House_in_Cappadocia_22.jpg" class="image">  ...(img tag, captions etc) </a>';
```

Add code here

```
preg_match('/<a href="(.*)" class="(.*)"/', $string, $matches);
if($matches[2] == 'image'){
     //set image code based on $matches[1] which is source of image or link
}
```